# XCode stuck on "Preparing Assets.car"

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

I am facing the following problem - I cannot run my application on iPhone 5s. After build, XCode freezes while showing the message "Copying Assets.car". Situation of this kind does not occur on other devices such as iPhone 6 Plus, 6s or 7. I have tried cleaning the project, removing the derived data, but unfortunately this did not help.

I also have not found any related topics on the web, so I will be really grateful for every reply.

[image: Screenshot:]